# Prevent timeout when connecting

Tags: groovy

I am using groovy to connect to a database and it works great with one my sources.  Recently, I have access to another database but I can seem to connect to it using Groovy.

I get the error(s):

Dec 20, 2013 12:22:26 PM org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.StackTraceUtils sanitize

WARNING: Sanitizing stacktrace:

oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Is there a way to extend the connection so it won't time out?

```
def db = Sql.newInstance(
    'jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.10.18.75:1521:radd',
    'report_user', 'createreport', 'oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource')
```

Comment: Are you able to connect from the same machine with other client? Your message error doesn't seem like timeout but connectivity issue (not reachable db host, for example)

Answer (score 2):

According to the Groovy API for [newInstance](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#newInstance%28java.util.Map%29) You should be able to pass in properties key value pairs and for Oracle use the ConnectionWaitTimeout property.

> def db = Sql.newInstance(
>       url: 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.10.18.75:1521:radd',
>       user: 'report_user', password: 'createreport', driverClassName: 'oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource', connectionWaitTimeout: 10)

Comment: But as an instance of java.util.Properties, not String. Groovy casting is shifty, but it won't be able to cast String as Properties, will it?

Comment: According to the docs it's just a string for that. Also I updated the example to be correct. I didn't see the note about using properties and how it effects username/password.

Comment: Could you point me to the specific part of docs? I have the sources of Sql class right in front of me (Groovy 2.1.7) and there is no method with parameter named properties and not being type Properties.

Comment: The link in my post is to the 2.2.1 docs and directly to the method public static Sql newInstance(Map<String,Object> args)

Comment: 1st of all sorry, I missed the link - it has almost the same color as regular text. But I was over the sources of this method as well. The doc is not explicit enough and can even be misleading. There is: _properties      a list of arbitrary string tag/value pairs as connection arguments_. So I would say it suggests a List not String, but how would one represent properties with a List? Anyway, inside the method source it gets pretty clear when you're coming across the line:
`Properties props = (Properties) sqlArgs.remove("properties");`

Comment: Easier and more straight forward is to just use Sql.newInstance(String, Properties, String). Though, in my opinion connection timeout isn't the root cause anyway.